# show text box in FolderBrowserDialog

Tags: vb.net, folderbrowserdialog

how i can show textbox in FolderBrowserDialog like below image,
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not directly possible, you have to fallback to using the shell function.  Project + Add Reference, Browse tab, select c:\windows\system32\shell32.dll.  An example of how to use it in a Winforms app:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim options As Integer = &H40 + &H200 + &H20
    options += &H10   '' Adds edit box
    Dim shell = New Shell32.ShellClass
    Dim root = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
    Dim folder = CType(shell.BrowseForFolder(CInt(Me.Handle), _
        "Select folder", options, root), Shell32.Folder2)
    If folder IsNot Nothing Then
        MsgBox("You selected " + folder.Self.Path)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't pass the 4th argument, it locks the user in the Desktop directory. C# version: https://bitbucket.org/snippets/mdelanno/yeGLnM

Comment: It is just an example, pass whatever directory you want to have on the top of the tree.

Answer (score 2):

Check this out : [FolderBrowserDialogEx: A C# customization of FolderBrowserDialog](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/159352/FolderBrowserDialogEx-A-C-customization-of-FolderB)

[image: customized FolderBrowseDialog]

The code is in C#, Here is the VB Conversion

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Diagnostics

Namespace DaveChambers.FolderBrowserDialogEx
    Public Class FolderBrowserDialogEx
        #Region "Fields that mimic the same-named fields in FolderBrowserDialog"
        Public Property RootFolder() As Environment.SpecialFolder
            Get
                Return m_RootFolder
            End Get
            Set
                m_RootFolder = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_RootFolder As Environment.SpecialFolder
        Public Property SelectedPath() As String
            Get
                Return m_SelectedPath
            End Get
            Set
                m_SelectedPath = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_SelectedPath As String
        Public Property ShowNewFolderButton() As Boolean
            Get
                Return m_ShowNewFolderButton
            End Get
            Set
                m_ShowNewFolderButton = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_ShowNewFolderButton As Boolean
        Public Property StartPosition() As FormStartPosition
            Get
                Return m_StartPosition
            End Get
            Set
                m_StartPosition = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_StartPosition As FormStartPosition
        #End Region

        ' Fields specific to CustomFolderBrowserDialog
        Public Property Title() As String
            Get
                Return m_Title
            End Get
            Set
                m_Title = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_Title As String
        Public Property ShowEditbox() As Boolean
            Get
                Return m_ShowEditbox
            End Get
            Set
                m_ShowEditbox = Value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_ShowEditbox As Boolean

        ' These are the control IDs used in the dialog
        Private Structure CtlIds
            Public Const PATH_EDIT As Integer = &H3744
            'public const int PATH_EDIT_LABEL = 0x3748; // Only when BIF_NEWDIALOGSTYLE
            Public Const TITLE As Integer = &H3742
            Public Const TREEVIEW As Integer = &H3741
            Public Const NEW_FOLDER_BUTTON As Integer = &H3746
            Public Const IDOK As Integer = 1
            Public Const IDCANCEL As Integer = 2
        End Structure

        <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet := CharSet.Unicode)> _
        Public Structure InitData
            ' Titles shouldn't too long, should they?
            <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst := 128)> _
            Public Title As String

            <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst := Win32.MAX_PATH)> _
            Public InitialPath As String

            Public ShowEditbox As Boolean
            Public ShowNewFolderButton As Boolean
            Public StartPosition As FormStartPosition
            Public hParent As IntPtr

            Public Sub New(dlg As FolderBrowserDialogEx, hParent As IntPtr)
                ' We need to make copies of these values from the dialog.
                ' I tried passing the dlg obj itself in this struct, but Windows will barf after repeated invocations.
                Me.Title = dlg.Title
                Me.InitialPath = dlg.SelectedPath
                Me.ShowNewFolderButton = dlg.ShowNewFolderButton
                Me.ShowEditbox = dlg.ShowEditbox
                Me.StartPosition = dlg.StartPosition
                Me.hParent = hParent
            End Sub
        End Structure

        Public Sub New()
            Title = "Browse For Folder"
            ' Default to same caption as std dialog
            RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop
            SelectedPath = "c:\"
            ShowEditbox = False
            ShowNewFolderButton = False
            StartPosition = FormStartPosition.WindowsDefaultLocation
        End Sub

        Public Function ShowDialog(owner As IWin32Window) As DialogResult
            Dim initdata As New InitData(Me, owner.Handle)

            Dim bi As New Win32.BROWSEINFO()
            bi.iImage = 0
            bi.hwndOwner = owner.Handle
            If 0 <> Win32.SHGetSpecialFolderLocation(owner.Handle, CInt(Me.RootFolder), bi.pidlRoot) Then
                bi.pidlRoot = IntPtr.Zero
            End If
            bi.lpszTitle = ""
            bi.ulFlags = Win32.BIF_RETURNONLYFSDIRS
            ' do NOT use BIF_NEWDIALOGSTYLE or BIF_STATUSTEXT
            If Me.ShowEditbox Then
                bi.ulFlags = bi.ulFlags Or Win32.BIF_EDITBOX
            End If
            If Not Me.ShowNewFolderButton Then
                bi.ulFlags = bi.ulFlags Or Win32.BIF_NONEWFOLDERBUTTON
            End If
            bi.lpfn = New Win32.BrowseCallbackProc(_browseCallbackHandler)
            ' Initialization data, used in _browseCallbackHandler
            Dim hInit As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(initdata))
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(initdata, hInit, True)
            bi.lParam = hInit

            Dim pidlSelectedPath As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
            Try
                pidlSelectedPath = Win32.SHBrowseForFolder(bi)
                Dim sb As New StringBuilder(256)
                If Win32.SHGetPathFromIDList(pidlSelectedPath, sb) Then
                    SelectedPath = sb.ToString()
                    Return DialogResult.OK
                End If
            Finally
                ' Caller is responsible for freeing this memory.
                Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pidlSelectedPath)
            End Try

            Return DialogResult.Cancel
        End Function

        Private Function _browseCallbackHandler(hDlg As IntPtr, msg As Integer, lParam As IntPtr, lpData As IntPtr) As Integer
            Select Case msg
                Case Win32.BFFM_INITIALIZED
                    ' remove context help button from dialog caption
                    Dim lStyle As Integer = Win32.GetWindowLong(hDlg, Win32.GWL_STYLE)
                    lStyle = lStyle And Not Win32.DS_CONTEXTHELP
                    Win32.SetWindowLong(hDlg, Win32.GWL_STYLE, lStyle)
                    lStyle = Win32.GetWindowLong(hDlg, Win32.GWL_EXSTYLE)
                    lStyle = lStyle And Not Win32.WS_EX_CONTEXTHELP
                    Win32.SetWindowLong(hDlg, Win32.GWL_EXSTYLE, lStyle)

                    _adjustUi(hDlg, lpData)
                    Exit Select
                Case Win32.BFFM_SELCHANGED
                    If True Then
                        Dim ok As Boolean = False
                        Dim sb As New StringBuilder(Win32.MAX_PATH)
                        If Win32.SHGetPathFromIDList(lParam, sb) Then
                            ok = True
                            Dim dir As String = sb.ToString()
                            Dim hEdit As IntPtr = Win32.GetDlgItem(hDlg, CtlIds.PATH_EDIT)
                            Win32.SetWindowText(hEdit, dir)
                            #If UsingStatusText Then
                            ' We're not using status text, but if we were, this is how you'd set it
                            Win32.SendMessage(hDlg, Win32.BFFM_SETSTATUSTEXTW, 0, dir)
                            #End If

                            #If SHBrowseForFolder_lists_links Then
                            ' This check doesn't seem to be necessary - the SHBrowseForFolder dirtree doesn't seem to list links
                            Dim sfi As New Win32.SHFILEINFO()
                            Win32.SHGetFileInfo(lParam, 0, sfi, Marshal.SizeOf(sfi), Win32.SHGFI_PIDL Or Win32.SHGFI_ATTRIBUTES)

                            ' fail if pidl is a link
                            If (sfi.dwAttributes And Win32.SFGAO_LINK) = Win32.SFGAO_LINK Then
                                ok = False
                                #End If
                            End If
                        End If

                        ' if invalid selection, disable the OK button
                        If Not ok Then
                            Win32.EnableWindow(Win32.GetDlgItem(hDlg, CtlIds.IDOK), False)
                        End If

                        Exit Select
                    End If
            End Select

            Return 0
        End Function

        Private Sub _adjustUi(hDlg As IntPtr, lpData As IntPtr)
            ' Only do the adjustments if InitData was supplied
            If lpData = IntPtr.Zero Then
                Return
            End If
            Dim obj As Object = Marshal.PtrToStructure(lpData, GetType(InitData))
            If obj Is Nothing Then
                Return
            End If
            Dim initdata As InitData = DirectCast(obj, InitData)

            ' Only do the adjustments if we can find the dirtree control
            Dim hTree As IntPtr = Win32.GetDlgItem(hDlg, CtlIds.TREEVIEW)
            If hTree = IntPtr.Zero Then
                hTree = Win32.FindWindowEx(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, "SysTreeView32", IntPtr.Zero)
                If hTree = IntPtr.Zero Then
                    ' This usually means that BIF_NEWDIALOGSTYLE is enabled.
                    hTree = Win32.FindWindowEx(hDlg, IntPtr.Zero, "SHBrowseForFolder ShellNameSpace Control", IntPtr.Zero)
                End If
            End If
            If hTree = IntPtr.Zero Then
                Return
            End If

            ' Prep the basic UI
            Win32.SendMessage(hDlg, Win32.BFFM_SETSELECTIONW, 1, initdata.InitialPath)
            Win32.SetWindowText(hDlg, initdata.Title)

            If initdata.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent Then
                _centerTo(hDlg, initdata.hParent)
            ElseIf initdata.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen Then
                _centerTo(hDlg, Win32.GetDesktopWindow())
            End If
            ' else we do nothing

            ' Prep the edit box
            Dim rcEdit As New Win32.RECT()
            Dim hEdit As IntPtr = Win32.GetDlgItem(hDlg, CtlIds.PATH_EDIT)
            If hEdit <> IntPtr.Zero Then
                If initdata.ShowEditbox Then
                    Win32.GetWindowRect(hEdit, rcEdit)
                    Win32.ScreenToClient(hEdit, rcEdit)
                Else
                    Win32.ShowWindow(hEdit, Win32.SW_HIDE)
                End If
            End If

            ' make the dialog larger
            Dim rcDlg As Win32.RECT
            Win32.GetWindowRect(hDlg, rcDlg)
            rcDlg.Right += 40
            rcDlg.Bottom += 30
            If hEdit <> IntPtr.Zero Then
                rcDlg.Bottom += (rcEdit.Height + 5)
            End If
            Win32.MoveWindow(hDlg, rcDlg, True)
            Win32.GetClientRect(hDlg, rcDlg)

            Dim vMargin As Integer = 10
            ' Accomodate the resizing handle's width
            Dim hMargin As Integer = 10
            ' SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth;
            ' Move the Cancel button
            Dim rcCancel As New Win32.RECT()
            Dim hCancel As IntPtr = Win32.GetDlgItem(hDlg, CtlIds.IDCANCEL)
            If hCancel <> IntPtr.Zero Then
                Win32.GetWindowRect(hCancel, rcCancel)
                Win32.ScreenToClient(hDlg, rcCancel)

                rcCancel = New Win32.RECT(rcDlg.Right - (rcCancel.Width + hMargin), rcDlg.Bottom - (rcCancel.Height + vMargin), rcCancel.Width, rcCancel.Height)

                Win32.MoveWindow(hCancel, rcCancel, False)
            End If

            ' Move the OK button
            Dim rcOK As New Win32.RECT()
            Dim hOK As IntPtr = Win32.GetDlgItem(hDlg, CtlIds.IDOK)
            If hOK <> IntPtr.Zero Then
                Win32.GetWindowRect(hOK, rcOK)
                Win32.ScreenToClient(hDlg, rcOK)

                rcOK = New Win32.RECT(rcCancel.Left - (rcCancel.Width + hMargin), rcCancel.Top, rcOK.Width, rcOK.Height)

                Win32.MoveWindow(hOK, rcOK, False)
            End If

            ' Manage the "Make New Folder" button
            Dim hBtn As IntPtr = Win32.GetDlgItem(hDlg, CtlIds.NEW_FOLDER_BUTTON)
            If Not initdata.ShowNewFolderButton Then
                ' Make sure this button is not visible
                Win32.ShowWindow(hBtn, Win32.SW_HIDE)
            ElseIf hBtn = IntPtr.Zero Then
                ' Create a button - button is only auto-created under BIF_NEWDIALOGSTYLE
                ' This is failing, and I don't know why!
                hBtn = Win32.CreateWindowEx(&H50010000, "button", "&Make New Folder", &H4, hMargin, rcOK.Top, _
                    105, rcOK.Height, hDlg, New IntPtr(CtlIds.NEW_FOLDER_BUTTON), Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, IntPtr.Zero)
            End If

            ' Position the path editbox and it's label
            ' We'll repurpose the Title (static) control as the editbox label
            Dim treeTop As Integer = vMargin
            If hEdit <> IntPtr.Zero Then
                Dim xEdit As Integer = hMargin
                Dim cxEdit As Integer = rcDlg.Width - (2 * hMargin)
                Dim hLabel As IntPtr = Win32.GetDlgItem(hDlg, CtlIds.TITLE)
                If hLabel <> IntPtr.Zero Then
                    Dim labelText As String = "Folder: "
                    Win32.SetWindowText(hLabel, labelText)

                    ' This code obtains the required size of the static control that serves as the label for the editbox.
                    ' All this GDI code is a bit excessive, but I figured "what the hell".
                    Dim hdc As IntPtr = Win32.GetDC(hLabel)
                    Dim hFont As IntPtr = Win32.SendMessage(hLabel, Win32.WM_GETFONT, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero)
                    Dim oldfnt As IntPtr = Win32.SelectObject(hdc, hFont)
                    Dim szLabel As Size = Size.Empty
                    Win32.GetTextExtentPoint32(hdc, labelText, labelText.Length, szLabel)
                    Win32.SelectObject(hdc, oldfnt)
                    Win32.ReleaseDC(hLabel, hdc)

                    Dim rcLabel As New Win32.RECT(hMargin, vMargin + ((rcEdit.Height - szLabel.Height) / 2), szLabel.Width, szLabel.Height)
                    Win32.MoveWindow(hLabel, rcLabel, False)

                    xEdit += rcLabel.Width
                    cxEdit -= rcLabel.Width
                End If

                ' Expand the folder tree to fill the dialog
                rcEdit = New Win32.RECT(xEdit, vMargin, cxEdit, rcEdit.Height)

                Win32.MoveWindow(hEdit, rcEdit, False)
                treeTop = rcEdit.Bottom + 5
            End If

            Dim rcTree As New Win32.RECT(hMargin, treeTop, rcDlg.Width - (2 * hMargin), rcDlg.Bottom - (treeTop + (2 * vMargin) + rcOK.Height))

            Win32.MoveWindow(hTree, rcTree, False)
        End Sub

        Private Sub _centerTo(hDlg As IntPtr, hRef As IntPtr)
            Dim rcDlg As Win32.RECT
            Win32.GetWindowRect(hDlg, rcDlg)

            Dim rcRef As Win32.RECT
            Win32.GetWindowRect(hRef, rcRef)

            Dim cx As Integer = (rcRef.Width - rcDlg.Width) / 2
            Dim cy As Integer = (rcRef.Height - rcDlg.Height) / 2
            Dim rcNew As New Win32.RECT(rcRef.Left + cx, rcRef.Top + cy, rcDlg.Width, rcDlg.Height)
            Win32.MoveWindow(hDlg, rcNew, True)
        End Sub

    End Class

End Namespace

'=======================================================
'Service provided by Telerik (www.telerik.com)
'Conversion powered by NRefactory.
'Twitter: @telerik, @toddanglin
'Facebook: facebook.com/telerik
'=======================================================
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues with the above dialogboxes (and any other dialog I've seen):

1: You cannot specify a custom start folder which will be preselected when the dialogbox opens, let's say "c:\temp"

2: When you type a path in the textbox and push TAB or ENTER this should NOT be seen as the final selected folder, but the treeview should instead move and expand to that path (just as if you did the same in Windows Explorer).

(sorry for putting this as an answer, cannot make a comment)